# How "LIKE" by LONG VARCHAR?

Tags: vertica

I had DB Vertica 8.0.
Create schema WAREHOUSE with table include field by type LONG VARCHAR.
Now I tried to execude SELECT for example

```
SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE.ALL_EVENTS a 
WHERE 
a.original_data like '%d963%'
```

returned error

```
SQL Error [4286] [42883]: [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
  [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4286) ERROR: Operator does not exist: long varchar ~~ unknown
```

In Oracle I used dbms_lob package for CLOB fields.

Vertica have simular package for LONG VARCHAR types?

How "LIKE" by LONG VARCHAR?

Comment: How long are the data in that column?

Comment: length 1 048 576

Comment: I don't think you can, I added an answer.

Comment: Is 1048576 the length of the longest string or how the column is defined?

Comment: this length showed DB SQL Developer - DBeaver. type LON VARCHAR selected because in Oracle was type - CLOB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertica documentation about `LONG` datatypes, in either [version 7.1](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/LongDataTypes.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Data%2520Types%7C_____5) or [8.0](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/DataTypes/LongDataTypes.htm%3FTocPath%3DSQL%2520Reference%2520Manual%7CSQL%2520Data%2520Types%7C_____5) states:

> **Notes**
>
> For optimal performance of `LONG` data types, HP Vertica recommends that you:
>
> - Use the `LONG` data types as storage only containers; **HP Vertica does not support operations on their content.**
> - Use the `VARBINARY` and `VARCHAR` data types, instead of their `LONG` counterparts, whenever possible. The `VARBINARY` and `VARCHAR` data types are more flexible and have a wider range of operations.

`VARCHAR` datatype supports up to 65K bytes long strings. You could use that instead, if the data are not longer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` instead of `LIKE`. Refer to [the Reference Page](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/RegularExpressions/REGEXP_LIKE.htm?Highlight=regexp_like) and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855562/how-like-by-long-varchar) of similar question. However you may not use `%` or `_` simple wildcard which supported by `LIKE` operator. In order to find more complex case, you should know about Regular Expressions.